# How can I use some controls on the form such an array of them

Tags: c#, winforms

I have about 20 checkboxes on the form. How can I name them to use them later in a for loop for example? A thing such an array `checkBox[i]`.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the controls are being created as part of `InitializeComponent()`, i.e. it's done by designer code.

The straightforward approach would be to do this after `InitializeComponent` is called:

```
var checkboxes = new[]
{
    checkBox1, // these are the names you have given
    checkBox2, // to the checkboxes in the designer
    checkBox3,
};
```

A better way would be to use LINQ to put all checkboxes in an array:

```
var checkboxes = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().ToArray();
```

However, this will not work recursively and you may have to filter some checkboxes out of the collection if you don't want all of them to be in the array.

Comment: thanks, helpful. but another question, how can I make them programmatically? not in design mode.

Comment: @OWE: Make one in design mode and look inside `InitializeComponent` to see how the designer translates it to code. Don't forget to call `this.Controls.Add(control)` after you have created `control`.

Answer (score 0):

Info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289500(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out container controls, they automatically create collections of the controls you place within them in design view.

Answer (score 0):

```
    CheckBox[] MyCheckBoxes = new CheckBox[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        MyCheckBoxes[i] = new CheckBox();
        MyCheckBoxes[i].Checked = true;
        //etc
    }
```